# Python GQL query not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
    ID = int(data_key)
    results = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientMeds WHERE patientinfo_ID='ID'")
```

where i have done wrong...

Thanks..

Comment: "not working" how? Be more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a parameter (examples [1](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_gql), [2](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html)):

```
ID = int(data_key)
results = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientMeds WHERE patientinfo_ID=:1", ID)
# or
results = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PatientMeds WHERE patientinfo_ID=:id", id=ID)
```

Comment: You shouldn't include quotes around the parameter in the GQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the more "Pythonic" model API:

```
from path.to.your.models import PatientMeds
results = PatientMeds.all().filter('patientinfo_ID =', int(data_key))
```